# Django: How to update the field of another model during object creation

Tags: python, django

I have a simple chat app.

```
class Thread(models.Model):
     participants = models.ManyToManyField(User)
     last_message_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class NewMessage(models.Model):
     message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
     thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, related_name = 'thread_to_message')
     datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Every time a a NewMessage object is created, I would like to update the last_message_time in the Thread model with the datetime from the NewMessage object that was just created. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is probably with a `post_save` signal handler for `NewMessage`.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def update_thread(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    created = kwargs['created']
    raw = kwargs['raw']
    if created and not raw:
        instance.thread.last_message_time = instance.datetime
        instance.thread.save()

post_save.connect(update_thread, sender=NewMessage)
```

You could also use a custom `save` method on `NewMessage`.

Comment: Mind the `raw` argument, too. It indicates whether the object has been created from a fixture or not. In case of the former case, you might end up with a ton of sql queries modifying your fixture data.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I think that's new as of 1.4, and I hadn't noticed it.